# cross domain problem with :OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

this code works with local kml files, but not when the kml files are on my other server,
I got 3 error :

```
OPTIONS http://192.168.0.150:9000/files/anonymous/AVGHDOP.kml 404 (Not Found) XMLHttpRequest.js:220
OPTIONS http://192.168.0.150:9000/files/anonymous/AVGHDOP.kml Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. XMLHttpRequest.js:220
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.150:9000/files/anonymous/AVGHDOP.kml. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

so, I try to put headers in the OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP. but it still is not working -_-.
here is my code:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: url_file,//the file is on an other_server(a play server).
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"},
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
            extractStyles: true,
            extractAttributes: true,
            maxDepth: 2
        })
    })
});
map.addLayers([osm, vectors]);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(osm));
vectors .events.register("loadend", vectors , function (e) {
    map.zoomToExtent(vectors .getDataExtent());
});
```

I dont know if I can configure a proxy. So if I can solve this problem without it it would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

You would solve this using OpenLayers.request methods, check this out:

> The above types of request are useful because they are asynchonous.
>   That is, the user can continue to view and interact with the original
>   page while additional data is being requested. A more common way to
>   request data asynchronously is to use the XMLHttpRequst object. With
>   an XMLHttpRequest object, you can open a conection to a server and
>   send or receive data via HTTP (or HTTPS). XMLHttpRequest objects are a
>   bit awkward to use and are unfortunately not supported in all
>   browsers. OpenLayers provides a cross-browser XMLHttpRequest function
>   and wraps it in some convenient OpenLayers.Request methods.

In this link you can find some examples to deal with your issue:

http://docs.openlayers.org/library/request.html

I think with this you can avoid using a proxy, but proxies are not a big deal in OpenLayers, check this out also:

https://collab.itc.virginia.edu/wiki/toolbox/Using%20A%20Proxy%20Script%20With%20Openlayers.html

Hope this helps,