# Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem when loading json file from Amazon S3 to display in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, amazon-s3, cors

This is my code for displaying geojson in OpenLayers, where "geourl" is directed to a json file in Amazon S3.

```
geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    url:geourl,
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()})
    });
```

But I received the error like this:

```
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
> (Forbidden) "geourl" Failed to load resource: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed
> access. "geourl" XMLHttpRequest cannot load  "geourl" No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed
> access.
```

Nothing changed when I added

```
self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

to my webapp RequestHandler Class.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I cannot load json file (stored in S3) to OpenLayers.

Comment: Possibly related: [Enabling CORS in OpenLayers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/71715/753)

Comment: It looks like there is no equivalent "crossOrigin" property on the [`GeoJSONOptions`](http://ol3js.org/en/master/apidoc/olx.source.html#GeoJSONOptions) class. Not sure what that means, though.

Comment: Very closely related: [Problem loading a GeoJSON file using Openlayers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/71715/753)

Comment: Yet another possibility: [cross domain problem with :OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/66385/753)

Comment: If you want to use CORS it may not be enough to just set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, you also need to handle the so-called preflight process on your web server. More info here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/